# how can i receive complete signal in nettyinbound?

Tags: netty, reactor-netty

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    TcpServer
            .create()
            .port(8080)
            .handle((in,out)->{
                return in.receive().retain().asString()
                        .doOnNext(System.out::println)
                        .doOnComplete(()->{
                            System.out.println("complete");
                        }).then(Mono.defer(()->{
                            System.out.println("do something else");
                            return Mono.empty();
                        }));
            })
            .bindNow()
            .onDispose()
            .block();
}
```

i want to do something after receiving the message from nettyinbound.

but it will never go to the function then() and the doOnComplete will not trigger.

if i switch the in.receive().retain().asString() to Mono.just("hello world") then and doOnComplete can be trigger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a TCP communication. Unless you have some specific protocol (to indicate end of the communication), you have communication between the client and the server (they exchange data) unless one of them closes the connection. Connection close in Reactor Netty for TCP is provided with I/O handler cancelation. The example above has to be changed to this one:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    TcpServer
            .create()
            .port(8080)
            .handle((in, out) -> {
                return in.receive().retain().asString()
                        .doOnNext(System.out::println)
                        .doOnCancel(() -> {
                            System.out.println("cancel received");
                        }).then();
            })
            .bindNow()
            .onDispose()
            .block();
}
```

Comment: oh . thx a lot . it's very thought provoking .

Comment: i'm trying to remake a tcp version  of gateway . and i saw on NettyRoutingFilter and saw the httpclient code like this